# Nintex Workflow - End Approval on First Rejection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

In standard Sharepoint Approval workflow there is option:

"End on First Rejection - Automatically reject the document if it is rejected by any participant"

How can i achieve the same effect in Nintex Workflow 2010 for action "Request approval"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Assign Flexi task control to assign task. and in that flexi task in Behaviour section you have multiple options on how workflow should go ahead

Answer (score 0):

Use a Flexi-Task in your workflow and use the option "First response applies" in behaviour, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "all must approve" option with the approval options of the **Request Approval** workflow task. Being that the workflow demands all approvers to approve an item before it is considered "approved" (still with me?), it will end on the first rejection, as there is no way that that item can then be considered approved. Thus, even if there are respondents outstanding, it will end with a rejection.